# Sending JSON from Postman returns code 200, Sending JSON from HttpClient returns 503 (Your chunked POST data is too large to upload)

Tags: c#, postman, ups

I'm making an API call to UPS using their Address Validation call (https://onlinetools.ups.com/rest/AV). I have had success calling different Gets from UPS before(example: UPS Address Street Level Validation).

Here is the JSON that is being sent:

```json
 {
    "AccessRequest": {
        "AccessLicenseNumber": "removed for security reasons",
        "UserId": "removed for security reasons",
        "Password": "removed for security reasons"
    },
    "AddressValidationRequest": {
        "Request": {
            "TransactionReference": {
                "CustomerContext": ""
            },
            "RequestAction": "AV"
        },
        "Address": {
            "City": "",
            "StateProvinceCode": "",
            "PostalCode": "98272"
        }
    }
}
```

In PostMan, there are only the default Headers being used:

[image]

This returns successfully with the data I am looking for with code: 200.

In my .Net Standard 2.0 Library, I am using HTTPClient(Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.7) to make a call to the API. Here is how I initiate the HTTP Client(variable called "ApiClient"):

```
string api = _config["UPS_API_LINK"];
_apiClient = new HttpClient();
_apiClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(api);
_apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
_apiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

Now I have created the models to line up so it sends the exact same JSON as Postman does. You will see with the code below that I double check that by serializing it myself (I take that string, copy it into postman, and works like a charm). So I send my request. I shortened the code a little bit make my point:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
Debug.Print(json);
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await ApiClient.PostAsJsonAsync("/rest/AV", request))
{
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Here is what the content returns:

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Weblogic Bridge Message</TITLE></HEAD> <BODY><H2>Failure of Web Server bridge:</H2><P><hr>Your chunked POST data is too large to upload.<hr> </BODY></HTML>
```

The return code is 503. So can someone lead me into the right direction? I just don't know what HTTP Client is sending that is making it so large that I get this response. Whats surprising to me is that I have another call to the api that sends more data and it works perfectly. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Note: I have double checked that I am requesting the call using the right URL

[image]

**Update:** Thanks to Nehorai, I discovered that I can use third party dll called RestSharp for making API calls. This library worked flawlessly! Though I would love to still know why HTTP Client does not work in this situation. Here is my code below using RestSharp incase anyone wanted to see it:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://onlinetools.ups.com/rest/AV");
client.Timeout = -1;
var requestRest = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
requestRest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
requestRest.AddJsonBody(request);
var result = await client.ExecutePostAsync<ZipInfo_RootResponse>(requestRest);
```

Comment: Probably because WebClient was using Chunked Transfer Coding, and Postman was using a content-length header.  You can set the content-length header on WebClient if you want.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I tried turning off chunked transfer coding, but still didn't help sadly. I'm just puzzled that I'm getting back this error when I'm not sending that much data at all. The call I make to another geter in their API requires more info in the header, and body. No problems with that call though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In postman, you can view a code snippet of the request, click on "Code":

[image]

Then you can select the language, select C# and you can see the request in C# code (you will need to add a reference to [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) dll)

Comment: Didn't know about this feature in PostMan. Thanks for the info! I also never heard of RestSharp before. But after implementing it, it worked perfectly. I still would like to know why Http Client does not do this.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Even though I depend on RestSharp, it does solve my issue, Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I just met a problem like that. May be the code and postman desktop have different network setting about proxy, the bypass proxy in my postman desktop is autobypass, but not for my code or postman browser. So what you need is to proxy setting.

[image]